# Menu Dinamico com Bootstrap

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap

Boa noite, como faço um menu dinâmico com o bootstrap? eu consigo fazer com link para redirecionar para uma pagina, porem estou fazendo um sistema e o seu menu é dinâmico como posso implementar?
menu.jsp--------------------

```
<%@page import="model.Menu"%>
<%@page import="model.Funcionario"%>
<%
    Funcionario fLogado = new Funcionario();
    try {
         fLogado = (Funcionario) session.getAttribute("funcionario");
        out.print("Nome:"+fLogado.getNome()+" | Perfil:"+fLogado.getPerfil().getNome()+"(<a href='sair.jsp'>Sair</a>)<br/>");
        for(Menu ml:fLogado.getPerfil().getMeusMenus()){
        out.print("<a href='"+ml.getLink()+"'>"+ml.getTitulo()+"</a> |");}
    out.print("<hr/>");
       }catch(Exception e){
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}
%>
```

Comment: Qual é o HTML gerado por esse código da pergunta? Aliás, é Java? Se sim, adicione a tag `java`. Considerando o HTML gerado, qual é o problema? O resultado não foi o esperado? Qual era o esperado?

Comment: Separe as coisas.. Abra um jsfiddle ou plunker quando sua dúvida for de Front End..  Não tem como responder sua pergunta assim...